# PowerShell script to update users' "Description" field with username as unique identifier

Tags: powershell

I have a CSV file containing just two columns - username and description.

I would like to update users' `Description` field in AD if their username is in this CSV.

The pseudocode for this would be something like:

```
foreach( Row in CSV ) {
    if( Row[username] exists in AD ) {
        ThisADAccount[Description] = Row[description]
    }
}
```

But frankly I have no idea how to do that in PowerShell!

In addition, at the same time, I would like to update these users' `E-mail` fields by setting `username@domain.com`. The pseudocode for this would be:

```
foreach( User in AD ) {
    ThisADAccount[E-mail] = ThisADACcount[Username] + "@domain.com"
}
```

This only needs to be done if the account's username is in the CSV file however so the expanded pseudocode to achieve both of these jobs in one fell swoop would be:

```
foreach( Row in CSV ) {
    if( Row[username] exists in AD ) {
        ThisADAccount[Description] = Row[description]
        ThisADAccount[E-mail] = ThisADACcount[Username] + "@domain.com"
    }
}
```

If someone could help me to convert this pseudo into working PowerShell, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you will need to import the `ActiveDirectory` module to be able to edit objects in AD via `PowerShell`. Next you use `Import-CSV`, note you will need to change the `-path` and `-Delimiter` parameters to suit your `CSV`. I have also presumed that your `CSV` column headers are (`username,Description`).

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$CSV = Import-Csv -Path 'T:\YourCSV.csv' -Delimiter ','

foreach( $Row in $CSV ) {
    if(Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(sAMAccountName=$($Row.username))") {
        Set-ADUser -Identity $Row.username `
                   -Description $Row.Description `
                   -EmailAddress "$($Row.username)@domain.com"
    }
}
```

You pretty much had the loop in the correct format for `PowerShell` you just need to use the cmdlets `Set-ADUser` to set the user properties and `Get-ADUser` to check if the AD user object exists.

Comment: Nearly, Richard - but not quite! I think you're very close though. The only thing which I believe will need changing in your code is the e-mail. I want to update the user's e-mail using their own username, e.g. if their username in AD is `j6test1`, I want to change their e-mail to `j6test1@ashingtonhigh.org`. My spreadsheet doesn't contain any information about e-mails.

Comment: @dunc I have updated my answer, I have also just seen an error if the user doesn't exist. Give me a min and I will fix it.

Comment: Nice work @Richard, thank you. Let me know when you've fixed that and I'll award you the answer.

Comment: Thank you Richard, that's excellent. Answer awarded. If I wanted to update the `Office` field at the same time, would that just be `-Office $Row.WhatEverTheColumnNameIsForOfficeInMyCSV`?

Comment: Yes that would work, if you want to see all the other options run the command `Help Set-ADUser -full `.